# EMScripten fails to build sample project

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to get EMScripten to work.  I'm quite confident that I've followed the tutorial, and made sure that the dependencies that are mentioned is installed.

While attempting to build a sample project, it fails like this;

```
tv@apu:~/git/emscripten$ EMCC_DEBUG=1 ./emcc tests/hello_world.c 

emcc invocation:  ./emcc tests/hello_world.c 
emcc: compiling to bitcode
emcc: compiling source file:  tests/hello_world.c
emcc running: /usr/bin/clang -m32 -U__i386__ -U__x86_64__ -U__i386 -U__x86_64 -U__SSE__ -U__SSE2__ -U__MMX__ -UX87_DOUBLE_ROUNDING -UHAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X87 -DEMSCRIPTEN -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -U__CYGWIN__ -D__STDC__ -Xclang -triple=i386-pc-linux-gnu -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -Xclang -nobuiltininc -Xclang -nostdinc++ -Xclang -nostdsysteminc -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/bsd -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/libc -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/libcxx -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/gfx -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/net -Xclang -isystem/home/tv/git/emscripten/system/include/SDL -U__APPLE__ -emit-llvm -c tests/hello_world.c -o /tmp/tmpMvgQiE/hello_world_0.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
emcc: will generate JavaScript
emcc: considering including libcxx: we need |[]| and have |[]|
emcc: considering including libcxxabi: we need |[]| and have |[]|
emcc: considering including dlmalloc: we need |[]| and have |[]|
emcc: saving intermediate processing steps to /tmp/emscripten_temp
emcc: LLVM dead globals elimination
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./emcc", line 837, in <module>
    shared.Building.llvm_opt(in_temp(target_basename + '.bc'), ['-internalize', '-globaldce'])
  File "/home/tv/git/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 545, in llvm_opt
    output = Popen([LLVM_OPT, filename] + opts + ['-o=' + filename + '.opt.bc'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The contents of `~/.emscripten`:

```
tv@apu:~/git/emscripten$ cat ~/.emscripten | egrep -v '^#|^$'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = os.path.expanduser('~/git/emscripten') # this helps projects using emscripten find it
LLVM_ROOT = os.path.expanduser('/usr/bin')
NODE_JS = 'node'
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp' # You will need to modify this on Windows
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

I have no idea what the problem is - and need help to troubleshoot.  Does anyone have any ideas about what can be wrong, here?  What did I miss?

Comment: What does "which clang" git you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest *Emscripten*?

Seems like your `LLVM_OPT` is not present. If the problem persists go into `/home/tv/git/emscripten/tools/shared.py` and before line 545 (`Popen([LLVM_OPT...`) add a line

```
print 'LLVM_OPT IS: <' + LLVM_OPT + '>'
```

At the next compilation this should print the path to `LLVM_OPT` to your stdout. And this path might not exist so you probably just need a symlink because the opt binary has a version appendix or such devilish stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your paths.  I'm working with Emscripten and after a series of confusing failures, it turned out my path information was incorrect.  Specifically my LLVM_ROOT.  This is the correct one for me:

```
LLVM_ROOT = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('LLVM') or '/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/bin') # directory
```

Note the location of llvm which is very different from the default /usr/bin that I had originally.  Note that even with the wrong path, the errors I was getting suggested emscripten was almost working.

Note:  I'm using Linux Mint 14 (Ubuntu Quantal).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your clang is either within your llvm directory of symlink it with something like this:
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang++ /usr/lib/llvm-3.2/bin/clang++